# Baidu map Cluster differentiates by changing the Zone

Tags: javascript, maps, cluster-computing, baidu, baidu-map

Default clusters for baidu map are changing when the number of markers clustering together changes but in the google map you can set it to have different colours outside of a specific  zone for example having grey colour for clusters outside of a city. How can I do the same for baidu maps?